# Edit standard email notification for approval process

Tags: email, approval-process

I need to add an email address as CC when the standard email for approval process is sent at Submit for Approval. Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you would need to disable the default emails that are sent since you can only specify the template on Approval Process setup page then send your own custom email alert as one of the Initial Submission actions.

Per this help doc, to prevent the send of the standard email template disable `Receive Approval Request Emails` option on User records.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004507&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

By Disabling the approval request from User record will disable all approval notifications, in case if we have more than one approval process then it will get disabled for all approval process notifications for this particular user.

I found one Solution for this, using queues, there is an option in queue to disable email notification for members:
[image]

1. Providing email address is required unless it will not work.
2. If we provide a valid email address then notification will go to only this email address not the queue members email address.
3. If we provide email with .invalid then no notification email will be sent.

Thanks,
Akash Biswas